# Printing specific parts from a file in shell

Tags: string, bash, shell, unique

I'm trying to print some specific information from a file with a specific format (The file is as following : `id|lastName|firstName|gender|birthday|creationDate|locationIP|browserUsed`
)
I want to print out just the firstName sorted out and unique.
I specifically want to use these arguments when calling the script(let's call it script.sh) :

```
./script.sh --firstnames -f <file>
```

My code so far is the following :

```
--firstnames )
OlIFS=$IFS
content=$(cat "$3" | grep -v "#")
content=$(cat "$3" | tr -d " ") #cut -d " " -f6 )
for i in $content
do

IFS="|"
first=( $i ) 
echo ${first[2]}
IFS=$OlIFS
done | sort | uniq
;;
esac
```

For example for the following file :

```
#id|lastName|firstName|gender|birthday|creationDate|locationIP|browserUsed
933|Perera|Mahinda|male|1989-12-03|2010-03-17T13:32:10.447+0000|192.248.2.12|Firefox
1129|Lepland|Carmen|female|1984-02-18|2010-02-28T04:39:58:781+0000|81.25.252.111|Internet Explorer
```

is supposed to have the output :

```
Carmen
Mahinda
```

One problem I've noticed is that the script prints the comments too. The above will print :

```
Carmen
firstnames
Mahinda
```

even though I've used grep to get rid of the lines starting with "#".
This is only part of the code (it's where I believe is the problem). It's supposed to recognize the "--firstnames". Since some of the fields from the file will have spaces in between, specifically in the last section(the browser section) , I wanted to remove just that section.
This is for a school project, and according to the program that grades this section, it's all wrong. The script works as far as I can tell though(I tested it). I don't know what's wrong with this therefore I don't know what to correct. Please help !

Comment: Can you show us a sample file content and how the output you need? By the looks of it, you can do it with a simple `Awk` as `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}!unique[$3]++ inputFile'`

Comment: `grep -vE '^#' inputFile | cut -d'|' -f3` should be enough, it looks like you're trying to do it in two different ways at the same time (bash native string handling with IFS + external tools handling with grep / tr / cut)

Comment: BTW to answer your specific question "why does firstnames still appear in my output", the problem is that the result of your `grep -v` was overwritten in the next line, where you started from the content of the file (`cat "$3"`) once again -> the effect of your grep (supposed to remove the commented line) was ignored

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grep -vE '^#' "$3" | cut -d'|' -f3` should be enough :

```
$ echo '#id|lastName|firstName|gender|birthday|creationDate|locationIP|browserUsed
> 933|Perera|Mahinda|male|1989-12-03|2010-03-17T13:32:10.447+0000|192.248.2.12|Firefox
> 1129|Lepland|Carmen|female|1984-02-18|2010-02-28T04:39:58:781+0000|81.25.252.111|Internet Explorer
>' | grep -vE '^#' | cut -d'|' -f3
Mahinda
Carmen
```

the `grep` command removes lines *starting with* `#` (it uses regular expressions to do so hence the `-E` flag ; if you want to keep removing any line containing a `#`, your current `grep -v #` is correct), the `cut -d'|' -f3` command splits the string around a `|` delimiter and returns its third field.

Comment: This seems to be working perfectly. Since I wanted to have them sorted and uniq I added  '| sort | uniq' and it worked. Thanks for explaining the answer!

Comment: @DimitrisDelis `sort -u` should be enough ;)

Answer (score 3):

**awk** would be best for your case

```
$ awk -F "|" 'FNR>1 && !a[$3]++{print $3}' file | sort
Carmen
Mahinda
```

`-F "|"` : To set `|` as field delimiter while reading fields in file
`FNR>1` : To skip first header line
`a[$3]++` : creates an associative array with keys as the string in 3rd field/column i.e in firstName and incrementing it's value by 1 each time the key is found. However the value of `$3` is printed only when `!a[$3]++` is true i.e when the key doesn't exist in the array or I should say the key is being read the first time.

Comment: @DimitrisDelis: I've added explanation in the answer.